# How to SuppressWarnings for 'common-java' rules

Tags: java, sonarqube

I need to temporary ignore rule "Insufficient branch coverage by unit tests" (common-java:InsufficientBranchCoverage).

Reading http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Frequently+Asked+Questions I see that `SuppressWarnings` should work for all rules.

But any combination of

```
@SuppressWarnings("common-java:InsufficientBranchCoverage")
@SuppressWarnings("InsufficientBranchCoverage")
@SuppressWarnings("java:InsufficientBranchCoverage")
```

does not work for me.

I use Sonar 5.0, Sonar Java plugin 3.0.

**Edit:**

This warning may be supressed (removed) from sonar UI. I see two solutions

- disable the rule 'Insufficient branch coverage by unit tests' for my quality profile. The drawback is, that rule is disabled for whole project, not just for single class
- mark issue as ignored when browsing issues drilldown. This ignores only single occurence of the issue. The drawback is, issue need to be marked in every sonar project (we have project-per-branch). When I need to remove warning, I must do this in sonar UI again, for each project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible.

The `InsufficientBranchCoverage` rule applies directly at File level and it is consequently not linked to any particular line in the file. To remove issues related to a given rule key using `@SuppressWarnings`, the rule has to apply at Class or Method level (as you can read in the documentation).

Note that to guarantee consistency of the results of the analysis, we can not disable the issue at File level, as it may end by hiding issues which would have been perfectly legit (take for instance the situation of a `java` file having multiple classes).

Comment: Sorry for hijacking your post, but does this also apply to the `common-java:DuplicatedBlocks` rule? If not, do you know any other way to exclude certain files from this check?

Comment: @Michael, I am using SonarQube Community Edition Version 7.9.1 (build 27448). Is it not possible to ignore `common-java:DuplicatedBlocks` in this version also? I tried putting `@SuppressWarnings("common-java:DuplicatedBlocks")` at both method as well as class level and it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, true.

To get rid of this warning you'll have to come with the big guns and prevent the sonar analysis for this file altogether:

```
<properties>
    <sonar.exclusions>**/ClassWithInsufficientCoverage.java</sonar.exclusions>
</properties>
```

This rule is especially annoying for classes having no fields, methods and constructors because it's only used for constants.