# @SupressWarnnings for InsufficientBranchCoverage in Sonar doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, sonarqube

I've already did the [steps mentioned in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343389/how-to-suppresswarnings-for-common-java-rules/29364599) with regards to ignoring the coverage on new code on sonar. Such as adding the @SuppressWarnings on the method or class levels (right above the method/class) w/ the ff. syntax.

```
@SuppressWarnings("common-java:InsufficientBranchCoverage")
@SuppressWarnings("InsufficientBranchCoverage")
@SuppressWarnings("java:InsufficientBranchCoverage")
```

However, the Coverage on new Code is still being reported in sonar.  Thing is, I've already reached the minimum required code coverage for the entire project as could be seen in this screenshot.
[image]

Hence I don't need it to be reported alright. This happened when I edited the code and removed the whitespaces and dead code in the project, and it just so happen that the part of the code being reported here not being covered is the thing I could not really have a unit test on.

Here's a snippet of my pom config below.

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Sonar -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0.1254</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Code Coverage Report -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>agent-for-it</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-site</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Is there something wrong with my config or declaration,or was the syntax already deprecated?. TIA.

PS:
I already tried

```
this.method() //NOSONAR
```

and

```
@SuppressWarnings("all")
```

@SuppressWarnings("all") is still reporting the code coverage in the Quality Gate. But it did remove the other warnings in the entire class or method. Just not the new code coverage being reported in the scan.

Comment: Please "try":  `//NOSONAR` or `@SuppressWarnings("squid:...")` source: https://www.google.com/search?q=sonar+%40suppresswarnings

Comment: ..and @suppress... annotation (can) also "takes" a `String[]` ;)

Comment: I already tried //NOSONAR , it doesn't work too. Also its good for one liner sonar exclusion only, I have like an entire method to exclude, //NOSONAR really isn't just that neat and clean in the code. there is no squid for the code coverage what's inplace of it is defined as 'common-java:InsufficientBranchCoverage' in the Rule where I had it reference.

Comment: (the *accepted* answer to) your cited question, states: "Unfortunately, it is not possible."  ..a "gentle counter-suggestion" (saddling the horse from "behind"): why not extend your test coverage (on new code)!? (this rule is reasoned)

Comment: oh shit, right. I overlooked that line on the answer,haha. Although I was able to work around this issue by creating another project and doing another scan as the project overall has 80%+ code coverage alright, just this annoying issue is appearing on the quality gate due to me editing an existing code, and due to a requirement, I need to be able to have a way to bypass this issue and have a passed status on the quality gate. Any other inputs other than this would be great really, I just really need the issue be gone for the project w/o creating another one.

Comment: Due to a (new) requirement/bug/code edit...i would write (at least) a new  test. (..covering the (new) sh...And every proper/experienced developer would agree!?) ...or at least adjust existing tests.

Comment: ..you should cover it! ..and make sonar, your team, your PO happy!:-)

Comment: ..except some corner cases (and sonar has a (default) 20% tolerance) , you can test-cover *(almost)all* of *own* code.

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to work with `@SuppressWarnings`, as we can read in the accepted answer to the question you referred to

> The `InsufficientBranchCoverage` rule applies directly at File level and
> it is consequently not linked to any particular line in the file. To
> remove issues related to a given rule key using `@SuppressWarnings`, the
> rule has to apply at Class or Method level (as you can read in the
> documentation).

I managed to do what you intend by configuring Sonar using `sonar.coverage.exclusions` [property](https://docs.sonarqube.org/9.6/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/).
In gradle:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.coverage.exclusions", "/src/<path-to-exclude/**,**/class-to-exclude.java"
    }
}
```

In maven:

```
<properties>
    <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
        /src/<path-to-exclude/**,
        **/class-to-exclude.java
    </sonar.coverage.exclusions>
</properties>
```